# How to generate PPCoins using Proof of Stake?

Tags: proof-of-stake, mining-technical-details, peercoin

PPCoins uses [Proof of Stake](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Proof_of_Stake) (in addition to Proof of Work) to generate coins.

1. Must the client be online for this generation to happen?
2. Do PPCoins stored in any web wallets / exchanges generate coins for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes
2. Yes, but it's not a great idea to do that. Coins need to sit in a wallet for at least 30 days before they start generating stake. I would never leave coins in an exchange\online wallet idle for 30 days.

Comment: Followup - should be client be online all the time? What about the first 30 days? After that period, can I turn it on once in a while, or should be be online all the time?